# Firestore use-case: can't search by hashtags and newest first

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

How is it possible to create a composite query with dynamically changing fields (e.q. hashtags) and ordering?

### Setup

I am using Firestore to implement the following:

- store items that the user can describe with tags/hashtags
- provide a way to query the items based on these hashtags...
- and order them by creation date...
- and use pagination or infinite scrolling or other way to limit the size of the results

The following structure was created to accomodate hashtags:

```
/items/{itemId}:
{
  name: "My favorite chair",
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  hashtags: {
    wooden: true,
    red: true,
    small: true
  }
}
```

And a query for 'small', 'red' items would would look like this:

```
const userSuppliedKeywords = ['red', 'small'];
let ref = firebase.firestore().collection('items');
ref = userSuppliesKeywords.reduce(
  (acc, key) => acc.where(`hashtags.${key}`, '==', true)
  , ref
);
ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').limit(20).get()....
```

### Problem

Due to using orderBy, Firestore requires an index for this search. But that is not viable, because an index for [hashtag.red, hashtag.small, createdAt] is not useful for the next query.

### Question

How is it possible to create a composite query with dynamically changing fields and ordering?

### Thoughts

- Queries based on user input are common, esp with hashtags
- Shouldn't download the complete result set, so pagination is needed
- Showing the newest results is also a common requirement

Is there maybe a better way to handle hashtags that make newest-first queries possible?

Is there maybe a 3rd-party service to help with this? Algolia seem to do only full-text search. Elastic documentation is a bit rough to figure out if it supports this use-case.

Another idea might be to have an array property with the hashtag permutations, e.g.

```
['wooden', 'red', 'small', 'wooden-red', 'wooden-small', 'red-small',
 'wooden-red-small']
```

Then this property can be indexed. Only one 'array-contains' clause is needed as per firestore limitations. But that leads to some ~ 2^n problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported naively with the Firestore `in` and `array-contains` queries, you can find more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).